# An analytical expression for the degree of a map from the sphere to itself

Tags: functional-analysis

Good morning to everyone.

I have found in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226624684_Large_solutions_for_harmonic_maps_in_two_dimensions) the following statement (not verbatim):

"Let $\phi$ be a smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the $3$-dimensional sphere $S^2$ which is constant far out. Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\phi\cdot\left(\phi_x\times\phi_y\right)
\end{equation}
is an integer. In fact this integer is the degree of the map $\phi\circ\pi:S^2\to S^2$, where $\pi$ is a stereographic projection from the sphere to $\mathbb{R}^2$".

The authors then provide a reference ("Niremberg, L.: "Topics in Nonlinear functional analysis") to support their claim.

Following this "hint" I tried and failed to prove this assertion. Can anyone help me? Any remark or suggestion is well appreciated.